# WP + Boostrap - How to hide menu after clicking menu item?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on website wpweby.cz/sbeauty and it is based on Brew (http://danvswild.com/brew/) which is base on Bootstrap. When you take a look at my website on mobile and you collapse menu and click on any item from menu, the menu stays visible.

I need help how can I hide menu after clicking menu item on mobile phone. I tried to search on stackoverflow but there I couldn't find how to deal with this in Wordpress.

Thank you

EDIT: here is code of my menu

```
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
</div>

<div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
  <?php bones_main_nav(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: You will have to show us some actual code that generates that menu. Just from the outside without a starting point this is more a job description than something that you actually need a _helping hand_. :) Hint: [the nav menu walker from your theme on GitHub](https://github.com/slightlyoffbeat/brew/blob/master/library/navwalker.php).

Comment: I edited my starting post, I believe this is classic bootstrap format of menu + there is php WP template tag to generate menu from Appearance - Menu in WP administration

Comment: And what is `bones_main_nav()`? What does it do and how does it do that?